# jsoup escape utf-8 characters into &eacute; ...etc... not in <script> tags

Tags: javascript, jsoup, entities

I've got a problem with an UTF-8 documentparsed by JSOUP into `<script>` tags

JSOUP converts:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>éà</title>
</head>
<body>
 éà
 <script>
   var x='éà';
 </script>
 </body>
</html>



<html>
<head>
 <title>&eacute;&agrave;</title>
</head>
<body>
 &eacute;&agrave;
 <script>
   var x='??';
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

how can I prevent this?

I already tried the 3 escape modes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `XHTML` as escape mode it shouldn't escape your html:

```
final String html = "<html>"
        + "<head>"
        + "<title>éà</title>"
        + "</head>"
        + "<body>"
        + "éà"
        + "<script>"
        + "var x='éà';"
        + "</script>"
        + "</body>"
        + "</html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "utf-8");
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);

System.out.println(doc);
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>éà</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  éà
  <script>var x='éà';</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

btw. [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has methods for [escaping / unescaping](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) HTML

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup does naot anything else as an odinary search and replace. The content within the script tag will be skipped, because the characters can be part of a name from variables or functions. And at least the `;` and `&` would viloate the convention rules for names.